# Change previous word after replacement

Tags: php, regex, templates

I have a template system that replaces every keyword inside curly brackets by the corresponding value from the database.

> Example: The company and the **{INSTITUTION}** agree...

The problem is that some templates are in Spanish and there is a rule that says when a word starts with the letter `i` the previous "and" connector is `e` instead of `y`.

Example:
The usual way is to say:

> Iván **y** Pedro.

But if the second name starts with `i` then the connector is `e`.

> Pedro **e** Iván

I need to find a way to do these replacements in order to get accurate documents.

I know I can do a double processing, first replacing the keywords and then replacing the pattern `" y i"` by `" e i"` but I'm not sure if that's the best approach to solve this issue.

The code I'm using for the replacements is the following:

```
$content = preg_replace_callback('#{(.*?)}#', 
     function ($key) use ($agreement) {
          return utf8_decode($agreement[strtolower($key[1])]);
     }, 
$content);
```

Where `$content` is the template text and `$agreement` is an array with the values from the database.

**Note:** It should be case sensitive. For example, if the text is `Pedro y Iván` it should be replaced by `Pedro e Iván` and not by `Pedro e iván`.

**Answer:** Based on the Chris' answer I finally ended up with this code that pays attention if the original `y` was upper or lowercase.

```
$text = preg_replace_callback(
    '#( [Yy] )?{(.*?)}#',
    function ($matches) use ($data) {
        $and = '';
        $replacement = utf8_decode($data[strtolower($matches[2])]);
        if ($matches[1]){
            $and_replacement = array(' Y '=>' E ',' y '=>' e ');
            $and = in_array(substr($replacement,0,1),array('i', 'I'))?$and_replacement[$matches[1]]:$matches[1];
        }
        return $and.$replacement;
    },
    $text
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match the y along with the keyword and replace it depending on the 
first letter of the replacement:

```
$content = preg_replace_callback(
    '#( y )?{(.*?)}#', 
    function ($key) use ($agreement) {
        $and = '';
        $repl = utf8_decode($agreement[strtolower($key[2])]);
        if ( $key[1] )
            $and = in_array(substr($repl, 0, 1), array('i', 'I'))?' e ':' y ';
        return $and.$repl;
    }, 
    $content
);
```

So in a template like:

```
{hombre} y {mujer}
{mujer} y {hombre}
sexy {mujer}
```

With `$agreement = array('mujer'=>'Isa', 'hombre'=>'Pedro')`, this should end 
up with:

```
Pedro e Isa
Isa y Pedro
sexy Isa
```

Comment: Thank you. Definitely, Isa is sexier than Ivan. :) I just made some little changes in order to identify if the original `y` was uppercase or lowercase.